# try except using files

Tags: python-3.x, exception

working on some code which requires to use try-except-finally. it needs to read through the lines of the file, break each line into a list of words, and then loop through each of the words in the line, and count each word using a dictionary.

this is my current code :

```
try:
  input_filename = input("Enter a filename:") 
  input_file = open(input_filename, "r")
  content_str=input_file.read()
  words_list = content_str.split()

  for word in words_list:
    if word not in counts:
      counts[word] = 1
    else:
        counts[word] += 1
  input_file.close()    

except IOError:
  print ("The file temp doesn't exist.")

finally:
  pass
```

Comment: The line `word = input_file.read()` reads the entire file into a single string. That string then becomes the only entry into `count`. You need to loop over the file line by line `for line in input_file:` and then break each line into words.

Comment: look at my edited code is it right ?

Comment: its still just short

Comment: Please don't edit your question about one error to be a question about a different error. In doing so, you make the (correct, helpful) answer that was written in response to the first version invalid. If your followup is very closely related, you might *add* it to the end of your question, but don't get rid of the initial bit.

Comment: As for your new issue, it depends on what key you're looking for and what's in your file. You haven't shown any code using the `counts` dictionary, nor the traceback of your new exception, so I doubt anyone can help you with it.

Comment: okay well instead of an "if"statement i am planning to put in a while statement in its place. when i did that the output was 3, 2, but it should be 2,1

Comment: sorry about changing the code :/

Comment: is their a way to do this without looping ??

Comment: I never have understood the question 'Can I do it without looping?' *Everything* dealing with an unknown number of multiple items has an implicit or explicit loop --- even if well hidden. That said, you can do `from collections import Counter; import re; Counter(re.findall('r'\w+',  input_file.read())`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is at your `if` statement. You check if `word` exists as a key in `counts`, and if so, you set it equal to `1`. **However, if it does not exist, you add one to it**. Thus, I assume you meant to switch the two around, try the following code:

```
count = {} 
try: 
  file_str = input("Enter a filename:")
  input_file = open(file_str, 'r') 
  word = input_file.read() 
  if word in counts: 
    counts[word] += 1
    print(counts)
  else: 
    counts[word] = 1
    print(counts) 
except KeyError: 
  print("Key error occured")  
except IOError: 
  print("The file temp doesn't exist.")
```

Comment: thats weird im getting an error >>>     print (counts['This'])
KeyError: 'This'

Enter a filename:{'This is a test\nThis is only a test\nDo not pass go\nDo not collect $200\n': 1}

Comment: I dont know why im getting a keyerror when ive picked it up ?

Comment: The dictionary you show in your comment has only one key, the multi-line string `'This is a test\nThis is only a test\nDo not pass go\Do not collect $200\n'`. Do you mean to be splitting it up by word or line? You'll probably need a loop!

Comment: i edited my code now with a loop but its missing something

Comment: is their a way to do it without a loop